# gradle exec command line: difference between separated and connected args

Tags: gradle, command-line, exec

gradle exec command line: difference between separated and connected args. e.g.,

```
exec {
   commandline 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'
}

exec {
   commandline 'arg1 arg2 arg3'
}
```

tried:

```
exec {
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', "mysql -u root -p123456", "-e \"create database foo\""
}
```

not working.

```
exec {
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', "mysql -u root -p123456 -e \"create database foo\""
}
```

works.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle exec is calling programs directly. Therefore it's different from writing text in a terminal. I think it is best explained if you imagine the main function of a program:

```
// exec { commandline 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3' }
fun main(args: Array<String>){
   // args == ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3']
}
```

```
// exec { commandline 'arg1 arg2', 'arg3' }
fun main(args: Array<String>){
   // args == ['arg1 arg2', 'arg3']
   // now depending on the program this situation could be handled or not
   val splitArgs = args.flatmap{ it.split(" ") }
   // splitArgs == ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3']
}
```

Terminals(for example cmd) usually do this split by space automatically.