# Is there a way to run helm commands in gradle task

Tags: kubernetes, gradle, kubernetes-helm

I'm using Gradle as the build tool and I need to run helm commands like `helm repo add` inside a Gradle task. I have tried as below.

```
      exec {
       workingDir = file("<Helm.exe location>")
       CommandLine "helm.exe repo add"
      }
```

But this fails with

```
Error: unknown command "repo add" for "helm"
Run 'helm --help' for usage.
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle exec is not doing any processing to the arguments. If you supply `"repo add"` as argument, helm will receive one argument: `"repo add"`. This would be the same as calling `helm "repo add"` in the terminal. What you want to do is, supply two arguments: `"repo", "add"`.

For more details see my answer here: [gradle exec command line: difference between separated and connected args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74190600/gradle-exec-command-line-difference-between-separated-and-connected-args/74195472#74195472)